# Conditional Formula using two string values to generate an integer?

Tags: google-sheets, formulas

I have a sheet consisting of information on items. These items have string qualities (Located on columns C & D) that affect a numerical value (Located on Column E). How do I use the IF Formula to generate an expected number derived from what is in the C & D cells of the corresponding row?

Right now I have the following:

```
=IF(C3="Pistol";+2; 
 IF(C3="SMG";+1; 
 IF(C3="Shotgun";+2; 
 IF(C3="Assault rifle";+2; 
 IF(C3="Sniper rifle"; +3;
 IF(C3="Rocket launcher"; +4; 
 IF(C3="Laser";+4;
 IF(D3="Tediore";-1; 
 IF(D3="Torgue";+2;
 IF(D3="Chrono";-2))))))))))
```

[image: On this graphic, note that the "Pistol" attribute should add 2 to the Rolled value, and the "Tediore" value should subtract 1, but it doesn't]

- On this graphic, note that the "Pistol" attribute should add 2 to the Rolled value, and the "Tediore" value should subtract 1, but it doesn't

Comment: problem is that your formula stops evaluating right after it finds "Pistol" and prints "2" into E cell

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solution:

```
=SUM(IF(C3="Pistol"; +2; 
     IF(C3="SMG"; +1; 
     IF(C3="Shotgun"; +2; 
     IF(C3="Assault rifle"; +2; 
     IF(C3="Sniper rifle"; +3; 
     IF(C3="Rocket launcher"; +4;
     IF(C3="Laser"; +4;))))))) + IF(D3="Tediore"; -1; 
                                 IF(D3="Torgue"; +2; 
                                 IF(D3="Chrono"; -2))))
```